# como acceder a una palabra de la url

Tags: javascript, url, split

estoy intentando obtener el primer parámetro o palabra de una url, es decir:
(catalogo.html?PALABRA-1&user)
lo que me gustaría es obtener después de ? y antes de & Y obtener (PALABRA-1)

he intentado con:

```
palabra=window.location.href.split("&",)[0];
```

pero me devuelve toda la url.

agradezco su colaboración gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución mas general, para obtener una salida similar a la que tendría `url.parse(req.url,true).query` en node, podría ser:

```js
const url = 'http://ejemplo.com?clave=valor&clave2=valor2';

const query = url.split("?")[1].split("&").reduce((p, c) => {

  let t = c.split("=");

  p[t[0]] = t[1];

  return p;

}, {})

console.log(query);

console.log(Object.keys(query)); //<-- Las claves como array
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como dijo Facundo, una buena opción es usar **URLSearchParams**.

Para tu caso puntual, suponiendo que solamente queres la "palabra" y no el valor, quedaría algo así:

```
const url = new URL('https://test.com/catalogo.html?PALABRA-1&user');
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

const [firstSearchParam] = Array.from(params.keys());

console.log(firstSearchParam)
```

Claro que si la url en cuestión, es la de tu ventana actual, tendrías que usar:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
```